# ADFC-50018 - getting a NullPointerException after closing a popup with a task flow inside

Tags: weblogic, oracle-adf

I'm working with Oracle SOA Suite 11.1.1.7.0 and I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

I've developed an ADF project which calls a task flow within a popup (that task flow is inside a jar added as a library to this project), so I just created a command button and I assigned to this the action which calls the task flow and shows it within an inline popup. I'm using page flow scope.

In my custom template I have an space to show some data, so I drag into it a fragment, that fragment accepts some collection models as parameters and shows all of the information in tables inside a tabbed panel.

So, I click the button, the popup with the task flow appears, I close the popup in order to get the output values (from the task flow), I try to interact with the tabbed panel and then I get the following exception (after opening a tab which uses a collection model passed as parameter):

```
####<May 28, 2014 3:45:32 PM GMT> <Notice> <Stdout> <tdcbpmis> <soa_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <5a72eb265a8db3ff:-38b3023b:1464055897b:-8000-0000000000031e92> <1401291932958> <BEA-000000> <<May 28, 2014 3:45:32 PM GMT> <Warning> <org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.skin.SkinFactoryImpl> <BEA-000000> <Cannot find a skin that matches family BCSSkin and version default. We will use the skin BCSSkin.desktop.>>
####<May 28, 2014 3:45:33 PM GMT> <Notice> <Stdout> <tdcbpmis> <soa_server1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <5a72eb265a8db3ff:-38b3023b:1464055897b:-8000-0000000000031e93> <1401291933086> <BEA-000000> <<May 28, 2014 3:45:33 PM GMT> <Error> <oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.AdfcExceptionHandler> <ADFC-50018> <ADFc: No exception handler was found for an application exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.<init>(JUCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:208)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierNodeBinding.<init>(FacesCtrlHierNodeBinding.java:66)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding.createNodeBinding(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:100)
        at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding.createRootBinding(JUCtrlHierBinding.java:411)
        at oracle.jbo.uicli.binding.JUCtrlHierBinding.getRootNodeBinding(JUCtrlHierBinding.java:107)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.RowDataManager.getParent(RowDataManager.java:260)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.RowDataManager.setRowIndex(RowDataManager.java:54)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.model.binding.FacesCtrlHierBinding$FacesModel.setRowIndex(FacesCtrlHierBinding.java:629)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXCollection.setRowIndex(UIXCollection.java:451)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXIterator$Runner.run(UIXIterator.java:531)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXIterator.processFlattenedChildren(UIXIterator.java:166)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:160)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:290)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:213)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailItemRenderer._encodeChildren(ShowDetailItemRenderer.java:373)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailItemRenderer.encodeAll(ShowDetailItemRenderer.java:120)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeStretchedChild(RichRenderer.java:2150)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelTabbedRenderer.access$2100(PanelTabbedRenderer.java:44)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelTabbedRenderer$BodyEncoderCallback.processComponent(PanelTabbedRenderer.java:1563)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelTabbedRenderer$BodyEncoderCallback.processComponent(PanelTabbedRenderer.java:1509)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:170)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:290)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.encodeFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:255)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelTabbedRenderer._renderTabBody(PanelTabbedRenderer.java:869)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelTabbedRenderer.encodeAll(PanelTabbedRenderer.java:326)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelGroupLayoutRenderer._encodeChild(PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.java:432)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.access$300(PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.java:30)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelGroupLayoutRenderer$EncoderCallback.processComponent(PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.java:682)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelGroupLayoutRenderer$EncoderCallback.processComponent(PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.java:601)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:170)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXSwitcher.processFlattenedChildren(UIXSwitcher.java:95)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:160)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.processFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:290)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.encodeFlattenedChildren(UIXComponent.java:255)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.encodeAll(PanelGroupLayoutRenderer.java:358)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.RegionRenderer._encodeChildren(RegionRenderer.java:1073)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.RegionRenderer.encodeAll(RegionRenderer.java:441)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.encodeEnd(UIXRegion.java:358)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.IncludeTag$FacetWrapper.encodeAll(IncludeTag.java:538)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.renderChildrenAfterHelpAndInfo(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:615)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer._renderContentCell(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:1163)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.renderContentRow(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:522)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.renderContentRow(ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.java:181)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.encodeAll(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:262)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.encodeAll(ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.java:107)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.renderChildrenAfterHelpAndInfo(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:615)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer._renderContentCell(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:1163)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.renderContentRow(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:522)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.renderContentRow(ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.java:181)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelHeaderRenderer.encodeAll(PanelHeaderRenderer.java:262)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.encodeAll(ShowDetailHeaderRenderer.java:107)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PageTemplateRenderer.encodeAll(PageTemplateRenderer.java:69)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.ContextSwitchingComponent.encodeEnd(ContextSwitchingComponent.java:155)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:220)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:422)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeChild(RichRenderer.java:2788)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:438)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1341)
        at oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1432)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:358)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:840)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:937)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:933)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.doRenderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:266)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:197)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:189)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:193)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:979)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:408)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:237)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:205)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:128)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:446)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:271)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.worklist.util.WorkflowFilter.doFilter(WorkflowFilter.java:175)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.bpel.services.workflow.client.worklist.util.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:70)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:180)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:324)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:460)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
        at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:163)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:252)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

I'm not sure if that was clear for you guys, but I'd appreciate every help I get.

Comment: Looks like a problem in some component binding. Need more details to tell something else (jsf code and backing bean code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've talk to the oracle support team and this was their answer...

> Looking at your stack trace, I have found a bug that matches your
>   issue :
>
> Bug 13953174 - NPE IN CURRENCYROWKEYSET WHEN ROWKEYCHANGEMANAGE
>   APPLIES CHANGES
>
> Additional bugs closed as duplicate of above bug :-  Bug 12874608 -
>   PS6:NULL POINTER FOR ROW SELECTION RELATED TO SELECTEDROWKEYS AND
>   SELECTIONLIST  Bug 13250742 - JEDI: NPE WHEN TEST OBJECT TASKFLOW IS
>   USED
>
> The fix for this bug is currently only available in versions 11.1.1.6
>   and 12.1.2

So... Yes, this is a bug and right now they're preparing a patch.